# Module Parse Failed while trying to implement scss into wepack & babel configuration

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, babeljs

i am trying to add scss to my webpack / babel configuration but when running npm run build it throws me the following error:

Since this is my first time using webpack as well as babel, I honestly have no clue what I have to change.

I created a repo with all my files. And did a screenshot of the error message. If you need any other information just tell me.
[image]

It would be awesome if we could fix my (probably garbage code) up to the point where it is running.
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to try `sass-loader`

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

For more info please look at this https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately i already did the suggested steps and followed the tutorial. Is it possible that I inititalized them wrong inside my webpack.config.js file? Or that I maybe created a wrong path while trying to connct the Files? [link] (https://github.com/Loligplayer33/Personal-Portfolio-Website) This is a link to my github repo. Maybe this could help. Thank you a lot for your time!

Comment: Problem is solved, Thank you!... It was a space in the webpack.config.js file.